# What tools are available for calculating code coverage using browser automation tests

Tags: code-coverage, selenium-webdriver

I have a website written in ASP.NET MVC 3. I have put together some browser automation tests that target this website. I want to use this same set of tests to calculate the code coverage of the website code.

I know that NCover does this kind of work but based on my knowledge there are two issues. One, NCover gives code coverage figures for both framework's code and my code. Two, it's costly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NCover has [filters](http://docs.ncover.com/ref/3-0/ncover-explorer/project-options/filters-page/) that you can use to ignore the framework code.

You could also use [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) or [PartCover](https://github.com/sawilde/partcover.net4) to get these metrics and they are both open source and free - they also have filters.

Hooking them into IIS is tricky but if it is for automation tests then you can run your tests against IIS express - much easier.

Comment: Hooking them into IIS is my primary requirement. Fine if they are tricky. do you know any articles that tell how to hook OpenCover/PartCover into IIS?

Comment: No articles that I am aware of, however you would/should get the same coverage results if you used IIS Express as if you used IIS. I always use this approach for PartCover as IIS hooking was always problematic due to how the profiler and it's console/host communicated.

OpenCover support for services, such as IIS, is in the pipeline for release 2, but again I'd still use the IIS Express approach in preference as it is so much simpler to setup and to repeat under test scenarios.

Comment: I would explore this more. In the meantime, do you know of similar features in-built into visual studio?

Comment: I think one of the more expensive editions of visual studio has code coverage support but I am under the impression it is for when running unit tests under mstest - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd299398(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I recently learned how to get code coverage data for browser tests running against IIS. I've documented how in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806421/is-it-possible-to-get-code-coverage-data-for-integration-tests-using-visual-stud