# Mutation Testing for Web Applications

Tags: selenium, web-applications, webdriver, web-testing, mutation-testing

I was wondering if there are any mutation testing tools for web applications. I understand there exist mutation analysis tools for specific server (PHP) and client side (JavaScript) languages to improve unit tests.

But, are there any mutation testing frameworks to measure the effectiveness of the UI test suites like Selenium Tests ?

Source code coverage seems to be a popular way to estimate the effectiveness of selenium tests ([JS code coverage with selenium tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544158/js-code-coverage-with-selenium-tests)). I have personally also used IstanbulJS to estimate javascript coverage. Since Mutation testing is considered better than coverage, I was wondering if there are any tools out there for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.

It seems very hard to make mutation testing on UI efficient:

1. UI tests usually take a lot of time
2. There's not really much logic, it's more like a set of steps to follow

Comment: I agree UI tests are supposed to be more about automating business specifications or part of user acceptance testing. However, there are efforts to ascertain coverage achieved by UI tests. Mutation testing is a logical follow up since coverage has been shown to be a poor indicator of test effectiveness

Comment: Right. But if you use selenium for instance, there’s no such metric as coverage if i recall correctly...

Comment: Indeed there are tools to do so. Here are a few from stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824990/c-sharp-code-coverage-with-selenium,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41544158/js-code-coverage-with-selenium-tests. 
Personally I have used IstanbulJS to find javascript coverage for selenium tests.