# Is it possible to get code coverage data for integration tests using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I am testing a ASP.NET application and would like to get code coverage information about how much of the product code my integration tests exercise. Our libraries are already instrumented and the symbols (pdb) files are available, but I need to know exactly how to enable Visual Studio to capture the code executing within IIS and return the .coverage file. My integration tests are a mix of web api tests and Selenium browser tests.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the Dynamic Code Coverage tools that ship with Visual Studio 2013. I'm using Premium, so I can't say for sure which versions may or may not have this component.

The command to start coverage and hook it into IIS is as follows:

```
<VisualStudioInstallDirectory>\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe collect /IIS /session:WebSession /output:<CoverageOutputFileName>.coverage
```

This will restart IIS and start up the coverage process.

Run your integration tests (or do manual testing if you want). When finished, stop the coverage tool with the following command:

```
<VisualStudioInstallDirectory>\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe shutdown /session:WebSession
```

This will complete creating the coverage file which can then be opened in Visual Studio. Note, that the shutdown command leaves the CodeCoverage.exe running. Restarting IIS will shut down CodeCoverage.exe processes.

A few other notes:

- If the specified output coverage file already exists, the code
  coverage monitor will not start. Make sure to use unique filenames or delete any existing files before starting.
- If you embed these commands as External Tools in Visual Studio, you
  need to launch Visual Studio as Administrator to get it to start
  correctly.
- If you want to convert your coverage file to xml so that it can be
  consumed by other tools (such as [ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator)), you can use
  the following command to convert the coverage file:

  \Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe analyze InputCoverageFile.coverage /output:OutputFile.coveragexml

Comment: This looked promising, and it does work for me if I only run one test. But as soon as I try to execute multiple tests, the coverage file that's produced will not open in VS. I get an error like "coverage file ... is corrupt or invalid". Not sure I fancy trying to run hundreds of tests individually and then merging the results :(