# Line that doesn't exist being included in dynamic code coverage analysis in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, code-coverage

I am trying to test out dynamic code coverage in Visual Studio 2017 for C++ following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806421/is-it-possible-to-get-code-coverage-data-for-integration-tests-using-visual-stud). However the coverage seems to be executing a line not in the program at all. This is the simple program I am using to test coverage:

**ConsoleApplication3.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Running..." << endl;

    if (false) {
        cout << "shouldn't print" << endl;
    }

#ifdef _WIN32
    cout << "Running in WIN" << endl;
#else
    cout << "Running in LIN" << endl;
#endif 

}
```

First I build using the `/PROFILE` flag (In Solution Explorer, right click the project then `Properties > Linker > Advanced > Profile > set to "Yes (/PROFILE)"`. To run my tests, I just need to execute the `ConsoleApplication3.exe`, so followed the instructions:

1. `codecoverage collect /session:qwerty /output:mytest.coverage .\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe`
2. `codecoverage shutdown /session:qwerty`
3. `codecoverage analyze /output:mytestCoverage.xml .\mytest.coverage`

NOTE: according to the post I shared above, it is not mentioned that you need to include the `.exe` as an argument. It implied you could start the collecting and then run your tests once collection had started. However, this just left me with an empty report and I found this to actually generate a real report. Next I converted the resulting `mytest.coverage` file to the `.xml` format. Opening up the `mytestCoverage.xml` I see the following:

**mytestCoverage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
   <modules>
      <module lines_not_covered="1" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_covered="6" blocks_not_covered="3" blocks_covered="10" line_coverage="85.71" block_coverage="76.92" id="A62F1CFD667E27408B95EED542B0A03801000000" path="consoleapplication3.exe" name="consoleapplication3.exe">
         <functions>
            <function lines_not_covered="1" lines_partially_covered="0" lines_covered="6" blocks_not_covered="3" blocks_covered="10" line_coverage="85.71" block_coverage="76.92" id="6832" name="_main" type_name="">
               <ranges>
                  <range end_column="0" end_line="6" start_column="0" start_line="6" covered="yes" source_id="0" />
                  <range end_column="0" end_line="7" start_column="0" start_line="7" covered="yes" source_id="0" />
                  <range end_column="0" end_line="9" start_column="0" start_line="9" covered="yes" source_id="0" />
                  <range end_column="0" end_line="10" start_column="0" start_line="10" covered="no" source_id="0" />
                  <range end_column="0" end_line="14" start_column="0" start_line="14" covered="yes" source_id="0" />
                  <range end_column="0" end_line="19" start_column="0" start_line="19" covered="yes" source_id="0" />
                  <range end_column="0" end_line="15732480" start_column="0" start_line="15732480" covered="yes" source_id="0"/>
               </ranges>
            </function>
         </functions>
         -
         <source_files>
            <source_file id="0" path="c:\users\sakeeb_hossain\source\repos\consoleapplication3\consoleapplication3.cpp" checksum="87CCE2DD760287BB1A6A3CCF2BF8B930" checksum_type="MD5" />
         </source_files>
      </module>
   </modules>
</results>
```

Take a look at the last `<range>` tag. My question is where is that coming from and how do I get rid of it (other than manually editing of course)?

Comment: Just a guess: `15732480` is `0xF00F00` in hex; looks like some marker. do you HAVE to remove it?

Comment: Maybe you should ask Microsoft. The provide a way to submit problem directly from Visual Studio. Does it does that for any source file?

Comment: @VladFeinstein Unfortunately, yes. The whole reason I'm doing this is to test out `SonarQube`, a tool I'm using for code coverage metrics. When I run the `sonar-scanner`, I the error `Line 15732480 is out of range in the file`.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yup, it does. Tried it with a different src file, a different project but still the same thing.