# Code coverage tool for Selenium UI Automation testing

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, code-coverage, ui-automation, test-coverage

I have a web application written in ASP.NET C# and hosted on IIS server.
I have a URL for my application as well e.g. mywebsite.com

I have written some browser automation tests using Selenium and C# that target this website through selenium Web Driver.

Test code example

```
[Test]
public void PageLoad_CountryDropDownShouldDisabled()
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("mywebsite.com");
    Assert.That(driver.FindElement(By.Id("ddlcountry")).Enabled, Is.False);
}
```

I want to use these tests to calculate the code coverage of the website code.

I found some information in below links but I am unable to do that.

- http://automationbyexample.blogspot.com/2013/04/visual-studio-2010-code-coverage-of-iis.html
- [What tools are available for calculating code coverage using browser automation tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782897/what-tools-are-available-for-calculating-code-coverage-using-browser-automation)
- [Is it possible to get code coverage data for integration tests using Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806421/is-it-possible-to-get-code-coverage-data-for-integration-tests-using-visual-stud)

Are any tools available for this and how to use those tools?
Please mention detail steps.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you happen to look at [Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/) and [istanbul-js](https://gotwarlost.github.io/istanbul/)?

Comment: I have used [dotcover(IIS-hosted web application)](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) for test coverage and its showing coverage report